# Export Oracle dump to remote disk

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export, expdp

So I have this task: export full database. There is a remote machine, on which Oracle 11g server is running. It is low on disk space, so exporting using expdp won't work.

Also, I do not have Oracle server on my local computer, so exporting using network link will not work for me. I used exp instead, but it has already been 4 days since I started export to my local disk (~380 GB already), but I need the dump file of the database.

P.S. I can connect to the remote machine using RDP. So if there are options that would allow me to export database dump using RDP I would appreciate if you could point to where to look.

I tried to search everywhere, even on different languages.

Comment: What do you want to do once you have the dump file?

Comment: Create a copy of that database on a different server, which will serve as a test database

Comment: If you can shutdown the source database it might be faster to copy the database files to the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nfs/cifs share on your system, mount it on the server and use datapump to export the data directly on the mounted share. You will still be limited by the throughput of the network link however.

You should also check the network connectivity between your machine and the server - there is no fast way to transfer 1TB through a 100Mbps network, for example.

Also, when using windows remote desktop, there is a way for the remote machine to mount and access your local drives. This way you can also use datapump export on a mounted drive. Just make sure not to disconnect the remote desktop session. But it will most probably be very slow.

Since you need to move a lot of data, I suggest that you consider using some kind of NAS or SAN storage, if available. And again - the most likely bottleneck will be the network.

Also, in order to speed up the export - consider excluding the statistics and synonyms. In earlier versions of 11g datapump had issues with exporting the statistics and excluding them sped up the process significantly.